# Need some help understanding the notation for Online Machine Learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning

I'm reading the Wikipedia article on Online Machine Learning and some of the algorithms mentioned there seem to be missing some context:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning#The_algorithm_and_its_interpretations

Specifically, in the first paragraph of the link above it mentions 
$H = \{ \langle w, \cdot \rangle : w \in \mathbb{R}^d \}$ and $V( \cdot , \cdot )$.

What do the dots represent in those equations?  I assume they're not a simple variable like $x$ or $y$, but it's hard to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: For subsequent questions please use LaTeX as you can learn from http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a standard notation to denote parameter positions, so $V$ here has two inputs, and $H$ here is a set of functions each with one input that is passed as the second input to the inner product (with first input being some $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ .